# Was this post useful to you - yes no - please!

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

Some of the other SE sites, e.g. Home Improvement have 'Was this post useful to you?' with yes and no buttons to click. I think we could benefit from the same. How do we go about getting that trialled?

Answer (score 3):

These are the feedback buttons for unregistered users. More details about the system here:

[Anonymous user feedback now in testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)

The idea is that, since unregistered users can't vote, this lets them give the sites some sort of feedback. Log out of any SE site and you'll see it, including Bicycles.

Answer (score 1):

We have feedback buttons already. It looks like this:

> [image: Vote Buttons]

Comment: Other SO sites have this too

Comment: @Neil Fein - thanks for correcting me on that!